# Rails 4.2.1: Cannot create record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

today I tried creating a new model like usual I created my controller first:

```
rails g controller Newsletters
```

Then I created my model:

```
rails g model Newsletter
```

Then I updated my migration:

```
class CreateNewsletters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :newsletters do |t|
      t.string :subject
      t.text :message
      t.string :recipient
      t.boolean :send, default: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Finally I ran my migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I setup my controller:

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @newsletters = Newsletter.all
  end

  def show
    @newsletter = Newsletter.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @newletter = Newsletter.new
  end

  def create
    @newletter = Newsletter.new(newsletter_params)
    if @newsletter.save
      flash[:success] = "Newsletter saved"
      redirect_to newletter_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
    newsletter = Newsletter.find_by(id: params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Successfully destroyed"
  end


  private
    def newsletter_params
      params.require(:newsletter).permit(:subject, :message, :recipient, :send)
    end
end
```

Now here is the problem. When I try to create a record in the console I get this error:

```
irb(main):001:0> newsletter = Newsletter.create(subject: "test", message: "test test", recipient: "all")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:48:in `__temp__3756e646'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:379:in `clone_attribute_value'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:122:in `old_attribute_value'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:94:in `write_attribute'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:50:in `__temp__375726a6563647'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:559:in `init_attributes'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/alexander/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):002:0>
```

What I tried this far:

1. I rolled everything back and removed all files generated and did it all by hand again.
2. I install the bundle again in case something is outdated

I don't really get what the error is so if someone could help me I would appreciate it a lot.

PS: I have read on github that it could be a problem with the "rb-fsevent" gem but my logs dont show the same thing:

https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/431

UPDATE:

My Newsletter model

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

PS: I am running ruby 2.3.0

Comment: Can you share your `Newsletter` model file?

Comment: It is empty, I will add it now

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`send` is a Ruby method and it leads to problems when you have an attribute with the same name.

Just rename that column to something else - like `email_send` or `was_send` and you will be fine.

Comment: Awesome, you were spot on. I renamed it to "email_send" and everything is working fine. Danke schön